# Splitting a string delimited by one or many spaces

Tags: excel, vba

I Have developed a vba application that reads a delimited text file and loads the data in to a Oracle table.

1. I am successful in splitting the string with comma, colon, semicolon and pipe delimiters.
2. The same code logic is not working for single or multiple space delimiters.

Since my logic is not working for space delimiter with split fuction,
I have used positional parameters and hard coded the field lengths.
But this has limitations.  Code needs to be modified basing on number of columns which is not appropriate and dynamic.

.1.  Sample of space delimited text file.

```
EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO
7369 SMITH      CLERK     7902 17-DEC-80 800             20
7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN  7698 20-FEB-81 1600    300     30
7521 WARD       SALESMAN  7698 22-FEB-81 1250    500     30
7566 JONES      MANAGER   7839 02-APR-81 2975            20
7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN  7698 28-SEP-81 1250    1400    30
```

.2.  Code used to split the records with delimiters , : ; |

```
     ' Load the file.
     fnum = FreeFile
     Open DataFile For Input As fnum
     whole_file = Input$(LOF(fnum), #fnum)
     Close fnum
     If whole_file <> "" Then
        ' Break the file into lines
        LINES = Split(whole_file, vbCrLf)
        ' Dimension the array.
        num_rows = UBound(LINES)
        ReDim Fields_Array(num_rows)
     Else
      MsgBox "No Rows Are Ported." & vbCrLf _
      & "Please Verify Whether The File Is Empty.", vbOKOnly + 
    vbInformation, "Data Porting Process."
    LogName.Write ("No Rows Are Ported. Please verify whether the file is 
    emply.") & vbCrLf
    Exit Sub
    End If

   ' Copy the data into the array.

    For R = 0 To num_rows - 1

    If cboDelimiter.Value = "Comma" Then
        Fields_Array(R) = Split(LINES(R), ",")
    ElseIf cboDelimiter.Value = "Colon" Then
        Fields_Array(R) = Split(LINES(R), ":")
    ElseIf cboDelimiter.Value = "Semi Colon" Then
        Fields_Array(R) = Split(LINES(R), ";")
    ElseIf cboDelimiter.Value = "Pipe" Then
        Fields_Array(R) = Split(LINES(R), "|")
    End If
    Next R

     Rs.AddNew
    For C = 0 To UBound(Fields_Array(R))
    If Fields_Array(R)(C) = "" Then
    Rs.Fields(C) = Null
    Else
    Rs.Fields(C) = VBA.Trim(Fields_Array(R)(C))
   End If                                
   Next C
   Rs.Update
```

3. Code used for positional parameters which is not dynamic

   #

   ```
     ' Data Loading Starts here
     Set InStream = fsys.OpenTextFile(DataFile, ForReading, False)
      Skip1:   Do While Not InStream.AtEndOfStream
      If Flag Then
      DoEvents

           FullLine = VBA.Trim(InStream.ReadLine)
           If VBA.Trim(FullLine) = "" Then GoTo Skip1
        If InStr(1, FullLine, "#", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then

        If Rs.Fields.Count = 1 Then
           'Table fields assignment
           v_F0 = VBA.Trim(Mid(FullLine, 1, 100))
        Else
           'Table fields assignment
           v_F0 = VBA.Trim(Mid(FullLine, 1, 4))   'Empno4
           v_F1 = VBA.Trim(Mid(FullLine, 6, 10))  'Ename10
           v_F2 = VBA.Trim(Mid(FullLine, 17, 9))  'Job9
           v_F3 = VBA.Trim(Mid(FullLine, 27, 4))  'Mgr4
           v_F4 = VBA.Trim(Mid(FullLine, 32, 9))  'Hiredate9
           v_F5 = VBA.Trim(Mid(FullLine, 42, 7))  'Sal7
           v_F6 = VBA.Trim(Mid(FullLine, 50, 7))  'Comm7
           v_F7 = VBA.Trim(Mid(FullLine, 58, 2))  'Deptno3
         End If
   ```

I would like to use more dynamic code some thing like the below 
but  it is not matching the column values correctly.

#

```
    ' Copy the data into the array.

    For R = 0 To num_rows - 1

    If cboDelimiter.Value = "Comma" Then
        Fields_Array(R) = Split(LINES(R), ",")
    ElseIf cboDelimiter.Value = "Colon" Then
        Fields_Array(R) = Split(LINES(R), ":")
    ElseIf cboDelimiter.Value = "Semi Colon" Then
        Fields_Array(R) = Split(LINES(R), ";")
    ElseIf cboDelimiter.Value = "Pipe" Then
        Fields_Array(R) = Split(LINES(R), "|")
    ElseIf cboDelimiter.Value = "Fixed Length" Then
        Fields_Array(R) = Split(LINES(R), " ")
    End If
    Next R

   Rs.AddNew
   For C = 0 To UBound(Fields_Array(R))
   If Fields_Array(R)(C) = "" Then
    Rs.Fields(C) = Null
   Else
    Rs.Fields(C) = VBA.Trim(Fields_Array(R)(C))
    End If                                
   Next C
   Rs.Update
```

Comment: Fixed-length fields are difficult to make "dynamic" - in some cases you can't even detect the boundaries reliably if one field runs right into the next with no intervening space.  So you really need some kind of specification for the files you need to load.

Comment: I have fixed my issue in 2 steps.  1.   I have removed  more than one space with one space.   2.  I have changed the values of null  data fileds with  "NULL"  worrds so that the delimiter  Space can be identified and mapped to the table columns  correctly.